# How do I check if temp view exists in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark

I understand how to check for table existence in PySpark:

```
>>> spark.catalog.setCurrentDatabase("staging")
>>> 'test_table' in sqlContext.tableNames()
True
```

But what about views?
If it create it like this:

```
df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM staging.test_table")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("test_view")
df.persist(p.persistLevel)
```

How do I check if "test view" exists later in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use sqlContext.tableNames and sqlContext.tables

```
>>> sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df, "table1")
>>> "table1" in sqlContext.tableNames()
True
>>> "table1" in sqlContext.tableNames("default")
True
```

Comment: it's very slow > 3 sec

Comment: For those using global temporary views: `sql_context.tableNames("global_temp")`

Answer (score 4):

"default" is the context where views are defined.

```
>>> spark.catalog.setCurrentDatabase("staging")
>>> 'test_view' in sqlContext.tableNames()
False
>>> spark.catalog.setCurrentDatabase("default")
>>> 'test_view' in sqlContext.tableNames()
True
```

This takes a bit of a time (>3 sec)

Faster would be to try/catch

```
try:
  _=spark.read.table('test_view')
  print('Exists!')
catch:
  print('Does not exist.')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what works for me using [`spark.catalog.tableExists()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Catalog.tableExists.html):

```py
from datetime import datetime, date
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()


df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=1, b=2., c='string1', d=date(2000, 1, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0)),
    Row(a=2, b=3., c='string2', d=date(2000, 2, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 2, 12, 0)),
    Row(a=4, b=5., c='string3', d=date(2000, 3, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 3, 12, 0))
])

# create a view
df.createTempView('demo')

# check if this view exists
print(spark.catalog.tableExists('demo'))
```